# Quadtree performance issue

Tags: performance, quadtree

The problem I have is that a game I work on uses a quadtree for fast proximity detection, used for range checks when weapons are firing.  I'm using the classic "4 wide" quadtree, meaning that I subdivide when I attempt to add a 5th child node to an already full parent node.

Initially the set of available targets was fairly evenly spread out, so the quadtree worked very well.  Due to design changes, we now get clusters of large numbers of enemies in a relatively small space, leading to performance problems because the quadtree becomes significantly unbalanced.

There are two possible solutions that occur to me, either modify the quadtree to handle this, or switch to an alternative representation.

The only other representation I'm familiar with is a spatial hash, and not very familiar at that.  From what I understand, this risks suffering the same problem since the cluster would wind up in a relatively small number of hash buckets.  From what I know of it, a BSP is a possible solution that will deal with the uneven distribution better than a quadtree or spatial hash.

No fair, I know, there are actually three questions now.

1. Are there any modifications I can make to the quadtree, e.g. increasing the "width" of nodes that would help deal with this?
2. Is it even worth my time to consider a spatial hash?
3. Is a BSP, or some other data structure a better bet to deal with the uneven distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use quadtree with at least 10 entries per node, but you'll have to try it out.

I have no experience with spatial hashing.

Other structures you could look into are:

- KD-Trees: They are quite simple to implement and are also good for neighbour search, but get slower with string clustering. They are a bit slow to update and may get imbalanced.
- R*Tree: More complex, very good with neighbour search, but even slower to update than KD-Trees. They won't get imbalanced because of automatic rebalancing. Rebalancing is mostly fast, but in extreme cases it can occasionally slow thing down further.
- PH-Tree: Quite complex to implement. Good neighbour search. Has very good update speed (like quadtree), maximum depth is limited by the bit width of your coordinates (usually 32 or 64bit), so they can't really get imbalanced. Scales very well with large datasets (1 million and more), I have little experience with small datasets.

If you are using Java, I have Apache licensed versions available [here (R*Tree)](https://github.com/tzaeschke/zoodb-indexes) and [here (PH-Tree)](http://www.phtree.org).